# Is it good to end a sentence with several adjectives without noun?

Tags: adjectives

Are "brilliant" & "white" both adjectives (in this case), or not? Is it good to end a sentence with several adjectives when noun is absent? Is it used only in informal English, or also in formal?

> **She was dressed in brilliant white.**

Comment: Do note that *white* functions as a noun here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, "white" *is* a noun. Colours can be adjectives or nouns.

Example as an adjective:

> She was dressed in **a** brilliant white **dress**.

Saying "she was dressed in white" is like saying "she was dressed in *cotton*" or "...in *silk*".